# Quarkus gRPC ExceptionHandlerProvider does not close response message with the correct status

Tags: java, grpc, quarkus, grpc-java, quarkus-grpc

I have a Quarkus gRPC server (reactive with Mutiny) and I want to customize the response status if an exception is thrown on the server side service.

[Repo to reproduce](https://github.com/jdussouillez/quarkus-grpc-exception-handler)

By default, when an exception is thrown, the server responds a gRPC status `UNKNOWN`. When some exception is thrown, I want to respond with status `INTERNAL` (or others).

To do this, I used the `ExceptionHandlerProvider` ([doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-service-consumption#custom-exception-handling)). The problem is that the method `ExceptionHandler::handleException` is never called (but [`ExceptionHandlerProvider::transform`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.16.2.Final/extensions/grpc/api/src/main/java/io/quarkus/grpc/ExceptionHandlerProvider.java#L22) is).

*Code simplified, real code [here](https://github.com/jdussouillez/quarkus-grpc-exception-handler/blob/master/src/main/java/io/quarkus/grpc/examples/hello/HelloExceptionHandlerProvider.java)*

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class HelloExceptionHandlerProvider implements ExceptionHandlerProvider {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ExceptionHandler<ReqT, RespT> createHandler(ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listener, ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata) {
        System.out.println("HelloExceptionHandlerProvider::createHandler");
        return new HelloExceptionHandler<>(listener, serverCall, metadata);
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable transform(final Throwable throwable) {
        return new StatusException().status(Status.INTERNAL); // TODO: transform the throwable to status exception
    }

    protected static class HelloExceptionHandler<I, O> extends ExceptionHandler<I, O> {

        public HelloExceptionHandler(ServerCall.Listener<I> listener, ServerCall<I, O> call, Metadata metadata) {
            super(listener, call, metadata);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Throwable throwable, ServerCall<I, O> call, Metadata metadata) {
            // This is never called!
            StatusException ex = (StatusException) throwable;
            call.close(ex.getStatus(), ex.getTrailers());
        }
    }
}
```

So on the client side, when an exception is thrown, the response status is still `UNKNOWN` (should be `INTERNAL)` but there is a `grpc-status` metadata value with value 13 (`INTERNAL` code value).

[image: Error response]

In the logs, everything is fine except that [the missing `handleException` call](https://github.com/jdussouillez/quarkus-grpc-exception-handler/blob/master/src/main/java/io/quarkus/grpc/examples/hello/HelloExceptionHandlerProvider.java#L53) :

```
HelloExceptionHandlerProvider::createHandler
HelloExceptionHandler::constructor
HelloExceptionHandlerProvider::transform - Should exit with status INTERNAL
```

Do I miss something here?

---

Another weird thing is that if I comment the `metadata.put(Metadata.Key.of("hello-error-code", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), ex.getCode());` line then the status is `INTERNAL` as expected. It seems that adding trailer metadata cause the response to fail with `UNKNOWN` status.

**Edit:** It seems fine when using the Quarkus gRPC client. This weird behavior is seen in Postman interface. See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/31110#discussioncomment-4956272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, same discussion -- answered here:

- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/31110#discussioncomment-4956320